# SQL Server CTE with function inside

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, inner-join

I need to do the following:

1. I already have function with name `CONNECT` with parameter `@table` of type `table`.
2. I need to assign `m2.ID` to `@c` variable, and then `select * from result of CONNECT( @c )` function. Variables `@a` and `@b` are declared and set earlier.

Code:

```
declare @c cat;

insert into @c 
  select m2.ID

select 
    m1.nazwa, @a poczatek, m2.ID, m2.nazwa, @b koniec, m3.nazwa
from 
    miasta m1 
inner join 
    miasta m2 on (m1.ID <= m2.ID and m1.ID = @a)
inner join 
    miasta m3 on (m3.ID >= m2.ID and m3.ID = @b)
```

Edit: I do not know why my code does not appear inside code block.

Comment: Your code didn't appear in a code block, because you have a numbered list (`1.`, `2.`) right above it. I inserted a simple line `Code:` and this solved it. If you what to format code or XML inside a numbered, you need to indent it by **8** characters (not just **4**)

Comment: Thanks for editing and improving my code, and sorry for accidentally spoiling it. Thanks for explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what is the type `cat` you are using to define @c. So are you trying to do something like this?

**EDIT:** As you have mentioned that `cat` is of type table, you can insert the `ID` into the @c variable, and pass that variable to `CONNECT` function.

Also not sure if a variable of type `cat` will go with a function with parameter of type `table`. You might need to update the function `CONNECT` to take in variable of type `cat` instead of `table`. Check the links here

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/168/

http://www.sailajareddy-technical.blogspot.in/2012/09/passing-table-valued-parameter-to.html

```
declare @c cat;

insert into @c
select m2.ID
from miasta m1 
inner join miasta m2 on (m1.ID <= m2.ID and m1.ID = @a)
inner join miasta m3 on (m3.ID> = m2.ID and m3.ID = @b)

SELECT * FROM dbo.CONNECT(@c)
```

If this is not what you need then please elaborate your question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: cat is type of table with 1 column of INT type :) I try to explain what I need in a short time. +1 from me, thanks